# Paste in new sheet after applying filter pastes nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro where it should get the last active line, copy all data to a new sheet, apply a filter (numbers on K row >15,9), copy and paste the results in a new sheet.

However, after aplying the filter, nothing is pasted in the new sheet.
Any ideas why?

Thank you!

```
Sub Macro1()

'Select and paste all data, couldn't work on a "last active line" in here..
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Plan2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1:O1").Select    
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Aplying the filter
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1056").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">15,9" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd

'Here I'm trying to past the filtered data in the new sheet, but the result appears in blank
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Plan3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'Here i came back and turned the autofilter off, but it was useless
Sheets("Plan2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$1056").AutoFilter Field:=11
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you think this criteria is doing: ">15,9"?

Comment: Could you not just filter the 1st sheet then paste the filtered data to the next sheet?

Comment: Problem may be the `DecimalSeparator` property in VBA you may need to use US-EN style notation: `>15.9` instead of `>15,9`.  Otherwise, most likely source of error is unqualified `Cells`/`Range` objects as per Scott's answer below.

Comment: David, it's not only the Decimal Separator, I've tried as you suggested and the problem persists. The ">15,9" it's supposed to filter numbers higher than 15,9

Comment: Davesexcel, that's the problem: In the macro, when I filter the 1st sheet and paste the the filtered data to the next sheet nothing's pasted. Manually it works, but in the Macro doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few issues in the code:

1. Using `Cells` can be very tricky, especially when you don't define them well
2. Using `Select` is never a good practice. Just stick with working directly with objects (Sheets, Ranges, Workbooks, etc.).
3. I don't know why you need to copy the entire data set to a new sheet, then filter it to copy onto a 3rd sheet. It's possible to just filter the original data set and copy to the final sheet. I did not adjust the code for this, because there may be a reason you need to do this, but so you know, you can just work with the original data without the middle step of copying to another sheet to filter.
4. You may need to filter on `15.9` instead of `15,9`, even if the comma is your decimal separator. (This may not be true, but I am adding it in in case it is (I don't have experience working on European systems in Excel.) Also, see David Zemens comment above.

In the below code, I have qualified all sheets and ranges, found the *last row* and provided comments where I made some assumptions. Modify it to fit your exact structure, and let me know if it works.

```
Sub Macro1()

'Select and paste all data, couldn't work on a "last active line" in here..

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPlan2 As Worksheet, wsPlan3 As Worksheet
Set wsCopy = Sheets("mySheet") ' replace with correct sheet name
Set wsPlan2 = Sheets("Plan2")
Set wsPlan3 = Sheets("Plan3")

'this will copy only cells with data in (*note -> this could copy more than that, but I will not go into it, for now, it's sufficient to use this)
With wsCopy

    'find last row
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1:O" & lRow).Copy 'assume the data goes to column O, change if need be

End With

With wsPlan2

    'paste to sheet Plan 2
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'find last row
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("A1:O" & lRow)
        'Aplying the filter
        .AutoFilter 11, ">15,9" 'you may need to use 15.9 here if you indeed mean 15 and 9/10ths. even if the comma separator is what you use to show decimals
        .Copy
    End With

    wsPlan3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'change range reference if you need it

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman, thank you very much for you answer!
It looks way better than the original, I tried your suggestion, however  when It runs,  the second line of your code is highlighted: 

    `wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPlan2 As Worksheet, wsPlan3 As Worksheet`

and it appears this error message:

    `compilation error: 'Illegal instruction out of a Type block`

Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `Dim` statement in front of the syntax. I have edited my answer to reflect this. Please try again :)

Comment: Amazing, now it works perfectly!
I just had to change the `15.9` to `15,9`, as you said.
Thank you very much, you helped me a lot! =)